# How to recover XFS file system which xfs_repair not work because of busy?

Tags: linux, xfs

I got problem in disk of my database which is xfs file system. I tried to repair

```
[root@scan /]# xfs_repair /dev/md127
xfs_repair: cannot open /dev/md127: Device or resource busy
[root@scan /]# ls /data
ls: cannot access /data: Input/output error
```

and dmesg

```
[35749034.608871] XFS (md127): Metadata corruption detected at xfs_inode_buf_verify+0x142/0x150 [xfs], xfs_inode block 0x410 xfs_inode_buf_verify
[35749034.610913] XFS (md127): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[35749034.611909] XFS (md127): First 128 bytes of corrupted metadata buffer:
[35749034.612903] 00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.613902] 00000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.614885] 00000020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.615569] 00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.616161] 00000040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.616747] 00000050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.617320] 00000060: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.617888] 00000070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
[35749034.618482] XFS (md127): metadata I/O error in "xfs_trans_read_buf_map" at daddr 0x410 len 16 error 117
[35749034.620782] XFS (md127): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x1) called from line 325 of file fs/xfs/xfs_trans_buf.c. Return address = 00000000bbf8b06c
[35749034.620785] XFS (md127): I/O Error Detected. Shutting down filesystem
[35749034.622724] XFS (md127): Please unmount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)
[35749034.624653] XFS (md127): xfs_imap_to_bp: xfs_trans_read_buf() returned error -117.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some processes still using `/data` filesystem. You will need to stop all the processes using /data and then try repair.

1. Check `lsof | grep /data` output and probably stop/kill processes using file kept in `/data`.
2. Unmount the filesystem using `umount /data`.
3. Then repair /data using `xfs_repair`.